# key: value vs key :value in ruby?

Tags: ruby, symbols

In associations, we usually do `a :b` (`belongs_to :something`). When we create a hash with symbol keys we usually do `a: b`. Having said that my question is what is the difference between the two syntax. Also is there any logic to memorize when to use which convention?

Comment: _"any logic to memorize when to use which"_ – understanding the syntax is crucial. Ruby is a great language for modeling sleek DSLs. But those just _look_ natural, you're still writing Ruby code after all. Try to think in terms of receivers, method names and arguments.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? Those two snippets of code do completely different things, and I don't really see any place where it would be possible to use both of them, so I can't really think of a situation where you could confuse the two.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are right. These two are different things. One is a method with params and other one is hash with key value pair. But looking them both looks alike and creates confusion which is now cleared below. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't about convention, it's about syntax.

`:something` is a [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Symbol.html).

`belongs_to :something` is a method that is being sent to an implicit `self` while also omitting the parentheses. We can write it as follows to make that obvious:

```rb
self.belongs_to(:something)
```

`:something` is thus just an argument being passed to the method `belongs_to`.

In a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html), we can use a `Symbol` as the key:

```
hash = { :something => "hello" }
```

Ruby introduced an alternative syntax in version 1.9 that can be used when the key is a symbol:

```
hash = { something: "hello" }
```

Both versions are equivalent.

Comment: For extra confusion: `{ "something": "hello" }` and `{ :"something" => "hello" }` are also equivalent.

Comment: @tadman For extra extra confusion: `{ :$x => 6 }` and `{ $x: 6 }` are not equivalent nor are `{ :@x => 11 }` and `{ @x: 11 }`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is between *method call* and *hash key*. They look very similar and can easily be confused if you're not sure what you're looking for.

In your first example:

```
a :b
```

In long-form this is:

```
a(:b)
```

Where now that's clearly an argument (`:b`) to a method (`a`).

In the other form it's different:

```
a: b
```

Where if that's part of a method call like this:

```
f a: b
```

Then that actually means:

```
f(a: b)
```

Which in full form is:

```
f({ a: b })
```

Where that's a hash definition following the `key: value` style. Here `:a` is the key (Symbol) and `b` is the value (variable or method call).

You'll often see `a: :b` where you have symbol key and value.

To differentiate between these two forms when reading code have a look at where the code appears to get a sense of context. When writing code, always frame your thinking in terms of *method calls* and *hash definitions* more clearly.